# how to make timer inside timer in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, timer

I want to make timer that makes cmd every 2 sec for 60 sec

```
timeout/t 60 
timeout /t 2
start everlast.bat
timeout /t 2
start everlast.bat
```

I dont even now how to do it

Comment: Well in the simplest form you can only run the cmd 30 times within 60 seconds if you want it to run every 2 seconds.  So a simple FOR /L command to loop 30 times should suffice. You could end up with it running longer because of the executing time of the secondary batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to explain better what you intend. I simply guess you might try to do something like this.

```
@Echo off
Echo Start %time%
For /l %%A in (1,1,30) Do Start everlast.bat & Timeout /t 2
Echo End   %time%
```

**Edit** Added time output to measure elapsed time

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to check the time you would need to convert the current time to seconds to do the calculations.

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do set /A "current=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)"

set /A expire=current + 60

:label
timeout /T 2 >nul
start "" "everlast.bat"
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do set /A "current=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)"
IF %current% lss %expire% GOTO label
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo off
set /a time=60
:timer
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set /a time=%time%-1
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set /a time=%time%-1
start everlast.bat
if %time% LEQ 0 goto EOF
goto timer

:EOF
exit
```

that should work if i'm correct